# Bad References: Found Please edit and resave the following items

Tags: upgrade

Anyone come across this issue, and if so, find a fix? These are a list of managed classes (installed package) that you are greeted with upon accessing the package within another packaging org.

[image]

I would guess this is after the Salesforce upgrade over the weekend.

Comment: Compile All Classes have any effect?

Comment: It fixed a few, but sadly not all - case in with SF now, cheers

Comment: What's the error in packaging org if you attempt (without changing it) to save a class?

Comment: No error, does nothing at all (the classes it is complaining about are in an installed package in the packaging org)

Comment: Try to re-install the same version of your installed package. This worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue. I also re-installed the package and a few classes got out of the list, but there are still triggers on the list. Any luck with the case with SF? (Uninstall the package is not an option to me)

Comment: It all seems fine in my org now, the issue is apparently fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug, which Salesforce have now fixed.

Removing and re-installing the package causing the issues also worked.

Answer (score 2):

To this problem, Salesforce has provided a button 'Recompile All' on the page where the 'Bad References' error is thrown. I clicked on the button to recompile all the classes and I was able to open my package components without any issues. Thereafter the error isnt thrown and the list of package components open as before.

Comment: This seems to work in most cases, but not in all.

Comment: I got a list of thirty or so classes when I tried to Save a new package. But after removing some extensions from Chrome, the "Recompile All" button worked quickly and my Package saved OK.